# Parsing, Extracting & Returning JSON as Hash

Tags: json, ruby

I am trying to make a localized version of this app:  [SMS Broadcast Ruby App](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/10/broadcast-text-and-picture-messages-using-ruby-google-spreadsheets-twilio.html)

I have been able to get the JSON data from a local file & sanitize the number as well as open the JSON data. However I have been unable to extract the values and pair them as a scrubbed hash. Here's what I have so far.

```
  def data_from_spreadsheet
    file = open(spreadsheet_url).read
    JSON.parse(file)
  end

  def contacts_from_spreadsheet
    contacts = {}
    data_from_spreadsheet.each do |entry|
     puts entry['name']['number']
     contacts[sanitize(number)] = name
    end
    contacts
  end
```

Here's the JSON data sample I'm working with.

```
[
 {
   "name": "Michael",
   "number": 9045555555
 },
 {
   "name": "Natalie",
   "number": 7865555555
 }
]
```

Here's how I would like the JSON to be expressed after the contacts_from_spreadsheet method.

```
{
  '19045555555' => 'Michael', 
  '19045555555' => 'Natalie'
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you have no problem with the whole JSON part? Then why ask about it?

Comment: I don't think `entry['name']['number']` is a thing in your data structure.

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting? Or what is the output from `sanitize(number)`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create array of pairs (hashes) using [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and then call [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) to get a single hash.

```
data = [{
    "name": "Michael",
    "number": 9045555555
},
{
    "name": "Natalie",
    "number": 7865555555
}]

data.map{|e| {e[:number] => e[:name]}}.reduce Hash.new, :merge
```

Result: `{9045555555=>"Michael", 7865555555=>"Natalie"}`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

How would I be able to make data = (file_url.json) instead of having the static array within the method?

Comment: `def spreadsheet_url
      'contacts.json'
  end'  

  def contacts_from_spreadsheet
    sample_data = open(spreadsheet_url)
    sample_data.map{|e| {e[:number] => e[:name]}}.reduce Hash.new, :merge
  end`

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear enough. Could you provide question in your post and describe an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have `number` or `name` extracted in any way. I think first you'll need to update your code to get those details.

i.e. If `entry` is a JSON object (or rather was before parsing), you can do the following:

```
def contacts_from_spreadsheet
  contacts = {}
    data_from_spreadsheet.each do |entry|
     contacts[sanitize(entry['number'])] = entry['name']
  end
  contacts
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really keeping this function within JSON, but I have solved the problem. Here's what I used.

```
def data_from_spreadsheet
  file = open(spreadsheet_url).read
  YAML.load(file)
end

def contacts_from_spreadsheet
  contacts = {}
  data_from_spreadsheet.each do |entry|
    name = entry['name']
    number = entry['phone_number'].to_s
    contacts[sanitize(number)] = name
  end
  contacts
end
```

This returned back clean array here:

```
{"+19045555555"=>"Michael", "+17865555555"=>"Natalie"}
```

Thanks everyone who added input!